# Inspecting a JSON string in RoR API

Tags: ruby-on-rails, json

An API is receiving a JSON string:

```
 Parameters: {"id_at_chain"=>"843_bac", "articoli"=>[{"articolo"=>{"centralecode"=>"16115", "descrizione"=>"Aperol ML.750",[...]
```

The controller properly logs

```
    Rails.logger.info params[:articoli]
```

as

```
{"articolo"=>{"centralecode"=>"16115", "descrizione"=>"Aperol ML.750",[...]}}  
{"articolo"=>{"centralecode"=>"604800", "descrizione"=>"DURANGO ALETTE POLLO"[...]}}
```

but when the array is processed

```
params[:articoli].each_with_index do |articolo, index|
  Rails.logger.info articolo
  Rails.logger.info articolo[:centralecode]
```

the whole item articolo is properly rendered

```
{"articolo"=>{"centralecode"=>"16115", "descrizione"=>"Aperol ML.750",
```

but the individual value `articolo[:centralecode]` is returning a blank

What is mistaken in the handling of this string?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`articolo` at that point is `{"articolo"=>{"centralecode"=>"16115", "descrizione"=>"Aperol ML.750"}` as you said. So, when you try `articolo[:centralecode]`, you're trying to find the key `:centralecode` in the hash `{"articolo"=> {} }` but the unique key available at these level is `articolo`.

To solve this, try this:

```
Rails.logger.info articolo[:articolo][:centralecode]
```

Comment: Yep!  I guess one should stop staring at things for too long!